# Volumes for lets encrypt SSL token in Docker and Nginx

Tags: docker, ssl, nginx, lets-encrypt

I am following this tutorial to implement SSL Certs from Let's Encrypt.

I set up a basic nginx config that Lets Encriypt can sent a token to. 
After that I am trying to receive a SSL Certificate by running the Certbot image manually:

```
sudo docker run -it --rm \
-v /docker-volumes/etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt \
-v /docker-volumes/var/lib/letsencrypt:/var/lib/letsencrypt \
-v /docker/letsencrypt/letsencrypt-site:/data/letsencrypt \
-v "/docker-volumes/var/log/letsencrypt:/var/log/letsencrypt" \
certbot/certbot \
certonly --webroot \
--register-unsafely-without-email --agree-tos \
--webroot-path=/data/letsencrypt \
--staging \
-d example.com -d www.example.com
```

And I am receiving the following error:

> Failed authorization procedure. example.com (http-01):
>   urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient
>   authorization

What has me confused are the volumes in the shell command. The folder "docker-volumes" does not exist on the host. Even after I run the command it does not get created.

Update: Output of /docker-volumes ls -la:

```
/docker-volumes/etc:
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Mar 17 19:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Mar 17 19:23 ..
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Mar 18 08:02 letsencrypt
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Mar 17 19:58 letsencrypt-docker

/docker-volumes/var:
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Mar 17 19:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Mar 17 19:23 ..
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Mar 17 19:38 lib
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Mar 17 19:38 log
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't related to docker. You need to change example.com -> your domain and make sure you pointed  domain to Public IP of the server.

Comment: Hey, yes - I removed the URL of my website for this post. When I run the command on my machine I use the URL of my website, that is listening via Nginx on port 80.

Comment: Your website must be public to the internet for let's encrypt verification . I mean other server can access to your website

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your answer. I am using a publically availible website. The A/AAAA Name is correct. I have an example app running. The problem (in my opinion really is) that I have a shared bind mount with certbot but even while performing the acme challange, I dont see certbot writing anything in the webroot. So naturaly it returns 404, since no folder is created...

Comment: which OS / distro you are using ?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.09.2 as OS on DigitalOcean Droplet

Comment: example: /docker-volumes/var/lib/letsencrypt:/var/lib/letsencrypt ... I think in the docker docs they refere to this kind of volume as a bind mount

Comment: /docker-volumes/etc:
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Mar 17 19:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Mar 17 19:23 ..
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Mar 18 08:02 letsencrypt
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Mar 17 19:58 letsencrypt-docker

/docker-volumes/var:
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Mar 17 19:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Mar 17 19:23 ..
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Mar 17 19:38 lib
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Mar 17 19:38 log

Comment: That was a good tip! I added the results to my initial post. I did try /docker-volumes la -a and it did not show the folder. But ls -a /docker-volumes/* actually returned something that I did not know was there before.

Comment: so i think you run multiple virtual hosts on nginx then certbot request to wrong host.

Comment: Heeey, lead me to a solution!!! I did not fully understood the directory on the linux server, I was on. I was in my non-root user directory /none-root in which the server directed me automatically on login. My absolute paths were faulty because they werde missing /home/non-root/..path.../ I struggled with this for soo lang ... thanks for pointing me in a new direction.

Comment: You run only one domain on your server, right? show me nginx config or root path of your site

Comment: yes, like I've said. I've solved my problem. I only run one domain from the server and my nginx.file is a super basic one server block. No proxies, no multiple virtual hosts

Comment: it was an error on my side that you cant really see i the code above. The code from the inital post shows that I mount serveral folders into the container of certbot. The path to which certbot writes the file for the agme challange pointed to the wrong folder. So, certbot wrote the file to a folder but that volder was not accessible for lets encrypt to validate the agme challange. So it was all do to faulty folder paths :)